# Prove an inequality of edges, vertices and valency of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Question: In any graph $G$, $|V (G)| = n$ and $|E(G)| = m$ is given. Recalling Cauchy-Schwarz ($|| ≤ ||w|| × ||z||$). Choose suitable vectors $w$ and $z$ to show $Σ_vρ(v)^2≥\frac{4m^2}{n}$. I am using $w=(ρ(v_1),ρ(v_2),ρ(v_3),\ldots,ρ(v_n))$,but I don't know what I should use as vector $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $z = (1, \ldots, 1)$.

Hint: Note $\sum_{i=1}^n \rho(v_i) = 2|E(G)|$.